# Why major axis length gives higher result than heigth value while using fitEllipse on Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I need to calculate major axis length,minor axis length and eccentricity.I am using fitEllipse() for calculation.But some object's major axis length  gives higher value then height value.I couldn't find to how fix the problem.

Here is the code:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    
    img = cv2.imread('Resources/son1.png')
    
    #input and output image
    def getContours(img,imgContour):
        #Find contours and set contour retrivial mode
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    
    
        #cnt is the one of the contours for every object in image
        for cnt in contours:
    
            # Contour for shape and I find area and length using this contour
            cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt,-1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

BoundingBox(Rectangle):gives the bounding box parameters => (x,y,width,height)

```
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            img = cv2.rectangle(imgContour,(x, y),(x+w, y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            print("bounding_box(x,y,w,h):", x, y, w, h)
    
    
            #W: and H: texts (Length)
            cv2.putText(imgContour, "w={},h={}".format(w,h), (x, y - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255,0,0),1,16)
    
            # give us specific contour (cnt) area
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    
            # Area text
            cv2.putText(imgContour, "Area: " + str(int(area)), (x + w + 20, y + 45), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                        (255, 0, 0), 1, 16)
    
            # # #Center of objects in picture
            #
            # M = cv2.moments(cnt)
            # print(M)
            # centx = int(M['m10'] / M['m00'])
            # centy = int(M['m01'] / M['m00'])
            #
            # print(centx,centy)
```

MajorAxislength,MinorAxisLength,Eccentricity

```
            (x,y), (minorAxisLength, majorAxisLength), angle = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
            ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
            cv2.ellipse(img,ellipse,(0, 0, 255), 2)
    
            #semi-major and semi-minor
            a = majorAxisLength / 2
            b = minorAxisLength / 2
    
            #Formula of eccentricity is :
            Eccentricity = round(np.sqrt(pow(a, 2) - pow(b, 2))/a, 2)
    
            x = int(x + w / 2) + 1
            y = int(y + h / 2) + 1
    
            cv2.putText(imgContour, 'Minor ='+str(round(minorAxisLength, 2)), (x+10, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1,16)
            cv2.putText(imgContour, 'Major ='+str(round(majorAxisLength, 2)), (x+10, y+20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1, 16)
            cv2.putText(imgContour, 'Eccentricity ='+str(round(Eccentricity, 3)), (x+10, y+40), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 0), 1, 16)
    
    
    imgContour = img.copy()
    imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (7, 7),1)
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgBlur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ImgThresh = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 100 , 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgGray,50,50)
    getContours(imgCanny,imgContour)
    
    cv2.imshow("Original Image", img)
    cv2.imshow("Canny", imgCanny)
    cv2.imshow("Contour", imgContour)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I added original image:
[image]

Here is the result image:
[image]

Comment: Is that actually a problem? The red hexagon kind of looks like a truncated ellipse anyway. I wonder what would happen if you drew an ellipse with a major axis of 110 and a minor axis of about 80, and then truncated the image so you were only looking at a 90x90 area centered on the ellipse. Would the major axis of the detected ellipse be 90 or 110?